# The spinner giff won't show

Tags: reactjs, spinner

I'm building a React app and would like a spinner to show when the api is fetching data. I don't get any errors with the way my code is set up, but I also do see the spinner in action. The app renders fine and functions as expected (except for showing the spinner). I've changed the value of loading in state to true and I still don't see anything. I've also styled the spinner to be really big so there's no way I could miss it on the screen. I've checked that I'm importing the right files...I'm completely stumped as to why it won't show. I guess it's possible that my Internet/code is working fine and spinner just flashes on the screen for a split second, but I'm pretty sure my Internet/coding is not that strong ;)
Thanks in advance for help.

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    films: [],
    alert: null,
    nominationList: [],
    loading: false,
  }

  searchForMovies = async (text) => {
    try {
      this.setState({ loading: true });
      const REACT_APP_API_MOVIE_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_API_MOVIE_KEY;
      const response = await axios.get(
        `https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=${REACT_APP_API_MOVIE_KEY}&s&type`,
        {
          params: { s: text, type: 'movie' },
        }
      );
      const { data } = response;
      const { Search } = data;
      if (data.Response === 'True') {
        this.setState({ films: Search, loading: false });
        console.log('ran');
      } else if (data.Error === 'Movie not found!') {
        this.setAlert(
          'Your search did not return any matches.Please try again'
        );
      } else if (data.Error === 'Too many results.') {
        this.setAlert(
          'Your search generated too many results.  Please enter a more specific search term.'
        );
      } else {
        this.setAlert(
          'We encountered an unknown error, please try another search term'
        );
      }
    } catch (error) {
      if (error === 'Error: Network Error') {
        this.setAlert(
          'We cannot reach the movie database.  Please check your internet connection'
        );
      } else {
        this.setAlert('We encountered an unknown error, please try again');
      }
    }
  };
 
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='App'>
        <Navbar name='Shoppies' />

        <div className='container'>
          <SearchBar
            searchForMovies={this.searchForMovies}
            clearMovies={this.clearMovies}
            showClearButton={this.state.films.length ? true : false}
            setAlert={this.setAlert}
          />
          <Alert alert={this.state.alert} closeAlert={this.closeAlert} />
        </div>

        <div>
          <ListOfFilms
            films={this.state.films}
            addFilmToNominateArray={this.addFilmToNominateArray}
            nominationList={this.state.nominationList}
          />

          {this.state.nominationList.length !== 0 ? (
            <NominationList
              nominationList={this.state.nominationList}
              removeFilmFromNominateArray={this.removeFilmFromNominateArray}
              loading={this.state.loading}
            />
          ) : null}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

AFilm

```
const AFilm = ({
  movieResult,
  addFilmToNominateArray,
  isNominated,
  loading,
}) => {
const { Title, Year } = movieResult;
if (loading) {
  return <Spinner />;
} else {
  return (
    <div className='grid'>
      <div className='card text-center'>   
        {movieResult.Poster !== 'N/A' && (
          <img
            src={movieResult.Poster}
            alt='poster provided by database'
          ></img>
        )}
      </div>
      <p>{Title}</p>
      <p>({Year})</p
      {!isNominated && (
        <Button
          text={'Nominate'}
          onClick={() => addFilmToNominateArray(movieResult)}
          disabled={isNominated}
          buttonStyle={'btn--primary--solid'}
          buttonSize={'btn--medium'}
        />
      )}
  
      {isNominated && <h4>Nominated!</h4>} 
    </div>
```

Spinner

```
const spinner = () => (
  <div className='spinner'>
   <img
    src={spinner}
    alt='Loading...'
  />
</div>
```

Comment: Can you display the entire file and gif, please?

Comment: Can you please re edit the code amd properly format with some more details about spinner component

Comment: Update the code!

Comment: share className='spinner' css details. where you define spinner variable (src={spinner} )?

Comment: You only pass the `loading` state to the `NominationList` component. Can you include all relevant code in your question please? If `NominationList` the `AFilm` component then it's only rendered when the `nominationList` state array is populated, so it likely isn't mounted when you are still loading any data.

Comment: Log the loading state and see what's happening

Comment: @DrewReese You're right! I passed the loading state into the wrong component. I passed the loading state into the correct component and now it works. Thank you!